# VPN - cannot connect trough internet (complicated network)

Tags: networking, router, vpn

the problem is that I can't connect to VPN through the internet connection, but it works on the local network.

I use no-ip.com service to connect to the first router, then It should allow me to connect to VPN on router 2 to access files from a computer on router 1 network.

[image]

All PCs from router 1 and 2 networks have no problem with connecting to VPN.

The first router is D-Link DWR-921 and it is 192.168.20.1 IP

The second router is ASUS RT-AC51U and it is 192.168.21.1 IP

For some reason, the first router can't access the second network, but second can access first.

EDIT:

Computer I want to connect to ip is: 192.168.20.3 and mask is 255.255.255.0, for now I've abandoned no-ip and using external ip to try and connect to vpn.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the IP of the computer you're trying to connect to and the subnet masks. What sort of connection are you making using no-IP to the first router?

Comment: Allright, but still I think I need to have forwarding.

Comment: Why such a complicated infrastructure for such a small network?

Comment: You see, first router have backup LTE support, but no VPN and second is other way arround.

Comment: which one oh these is the VPN server ????

Comment: second network pc have vpn

Answer (score 0):

Router one will have an Inside Network and Outside Network. Make sure you have ports open on Router 1 to allow access from Outside (connected to Router 2) back to Inside (connected to PC1).

Comment: Allright, I try to set this up, but what ports are needed and how to set them here: https://i.imgur.com/TrOiQer.png

Comment: Depends on how are you connecting to PC1. If it is rdp, than port 3389 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the 2nd router can access the first subnet but not vice-versa is because of double nating.

On router 2 set it's local address to the range of the first, something like 192.168.20.254. then in router 2 disable DHCP, disable firewall/spi, disable the WAN, and make sure your connecting router 2 from the lan ports, to the lan ports of router one.

You should now be able to communicate in both directions no problem.